# Slider with jQuery using bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider with 3 images and left/right arrows. If you click on them, the image changes. You also have 3 bullets below the images and the image changes depending on what bullet you click.

I don't want to use buttons "arrows"; I want to use the tag "a." Any ideas on making it better? You'll need to add 3 images "because sliders use 3 images"
and the other 2 images are to use left/right arrows (to change the images). That is what I don't want to use, as I said.

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slider</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sliders">
    <ul >
        <li class="activa"><img src="fotos-de-Hamburguesa-americana.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images (3).jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images21312.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
<!--    <ul class="controles">
        <li class="activa">&nbsp</li>
        <li>&nbsp</li>
        <li>&nbsp</li>
    </ul> -->
</div>
<div class="sliders">
    <ul>
        <li class="activa"><img src="fotos-de-Hamburguesa-americana.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images (3).jpg"></li>
<!--        <li><img src="images21312.jpg"></li> -->
    </ul>   

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```js
$.fn.slider = function(config){
    var nodos = this;
    var delay = (typeof config.delay == "number")?parseInt(config.delay):4000;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodos.length; i++) {
        Slider(nodos[i]);
    }
    function Slider(nodo){
        var galeria = $(nodo).find('ul');
        var btn1 = "<button class='before'></button>";
        if(!$(nodo).hasClass('slider'))
        $(nodo).addClass('slider');

        if(!galeria.hasClass('galeria'))
        galeria.addClass("galeria");

        //Encontrar cuantas imagenes hay en la galeria
        var imagenes = $(galeria).find('li');

        //Controles
        var html_bullets="<ul class='controles'>";
        for (var it = 0; it < imagenes.length; it++) {
            if(it==0)
            html_bullets+="<li data-index='"+it+"' class='activa'>&nbsp;</li>";
            else    
            html_bullets+="<li data-index='"+it+"'>&nbsp;</li>";
        }

        html_bullets+="</ul><button class='next'></button>";
        $(nodo).append(html_bullets);
        $(nodo).prepend(btn1);
        var bullets = $(nodo).find("ul.controles li");
        bullets.click(function(){
        var index= $(this).data("index");
        bullets.removeClass('activa');
        imagenes.removeClass('activa');
        $(imagenes[index]).addClass("activa");  
        $(bullets[index]).addClass("activa");   
        });
    }
        $(".slider").on("click","button.before",function(){
            var div = this;
            div = $(div).parent();
            console.log(div);
            flechas({div:div});
        });
        $(".slider").on("click","button.next",function(){
            var div = this;
            div = $(div).parent();
            flechas({div:div,direccion:1});
        }); 

        function flechas(tipo){
            var div = tipo.div;
            var imagen = $(div).find("ul.galeria li.activa");
            var imagenes = $(div).find("ul.galeria li");
            var bullet = $(div).find("ul.controles li.activa");
            var bullets = $(div).find("ul.controles li");
            var index = bullet.data("index");
            var max = bullets.length-1;
            bullets.removeClass('activa');
            imagenes.removeClass('activa');
        if(tipo.direccion){
            if(index == max){
            $(imagenes[0]).addClass("activa");  
            $(bullets[0]).addClass("activa");   
            }else {
            $(imagenes[index+1]).addClass("activa");    
            $(bullets[index+1]).addClass("activa"); 
            }   
        }
        else{
            if(index == 0){
            $(imagenes[max]).addClass("activa");    
            $(bullets[max]).addClass("activa"); 
            }else {
            $(imagenes[index-1]).addClass("activa");    
            $(bullets[index-1]).addClass("activa"); 
            }
        }

        }   
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".sliders").slider({delay:5000});

});
```

**CSS:**

```css
.slider{
    width: 420px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; 
}

.slider ul.galeria{
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.slider ul.galeria li{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.slider ul.galeria li.activa{
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider ul.galeria img{
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left: 5px;   
}

/*Controles*/
.slider ul.controles {
    text-align: center;
}

.slider ul.controles li{
    background-color: black ;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.slider ul.controles li.activa{
    background-color: blue ;
}
/*Botones-flechas*/
.slider button.before{
    background-image: url(Flecha_002.png);
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 128px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 28px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 33px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
}
.slider button.next{
    background-image: url(Flecha_001.png);
    position: relative;
    left: 86%;
    bottom: 190px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 28px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 33px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
}   
.slider button.before:focus{
    outline: none;
}   
.slider button.next:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.slider button.before:hover,.slider button.next:hover,.slider ul.controles li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good, but there's some points you can improve upon:

---

## Assumptions:

> ```
> $.fn.slider = function(config){
>     var nodos = this;
>     var delay = (typeof config.delay == "number")?parseInt(config.delay):4000;
> ```

You're assuming `config` won't be empty or not added. You should have a default config, and simply extend the parameter config to include the items the parameter config left off.

---

## <sup>*ab*</sup>using jQuery:

You may not need to use jQuery for everything: See [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com) for a full list.

For example:

- `$(nodo).find('ul')` can be written as `nodo.getElementsByTagName('ul')`
- `$(this).data("index")` can be written as `this.getAttribute('index')`
- `$(div).parent()` can be written as `div.parentElement`
- `.addClass` can be written as `.classList.add`

---

## Better call the redundancy department department:

Your code has quite a bit of redundancy, for example:

> ```
> var div = this;
> div = $(div).parent();
> console.log(div);
> flechas({div:div});
> ```

Could be expressed as:

```
flechas({div: this.parentElement});
```

And the following is also redundant:

> 

```
var btn1 = "<button class='before'></button>";
var html_bullets="<ul class='controles'>";
html_bullets+="...";
$(nodo).append(html_bullets);
$(nodo).prepend(btn1);
```

Simply remove `btn1` and attach its contents to `html_bullets`.

---

## Indentation and spacing:

Your indentation and spacing is wrong:

- You should have spaces around your operators and after commas.
- You should have each layer of indentation indented by either two, four or eight spaces. Additionally, keep consistent.

---

## Miscellanous

- `typeof` vs. `instanceof`: While both are similar, I would prefer to use `instanceof` as it lets you declare the type as the type, meaning the compiler will pick up if you mess up the format on the name:

```
if (config.delay instanceof Number)
```

- `parseInt(config.delay)`: there's many ways to do this [as described by this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/3296811), however, I would prefer `Number(config.delay)` as it looks more clear as to what are trying to create.

  - In addition to this above point, leaving off the second parameter in `parseInt` can cause strange issues. Unless needed, you can use `10` as the second parameter to parse to decimal.

Comment: That's really nice information, thanks for your time and help I'll have on mind that tips